# Can I add images for variable products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I know, how can I add images for variable products.
I want to add image in variable product description area, as I can do it for simple product's short description.

How is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add or replace a variation fields into a WYSIWYG editor field in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867300/add-or-replace-a-variation-fields-into-a-wysiwyg-editor-field-in-woocommerce)

Answer (score -1):

Hy, Please Follow These steps to add images in a variable product.

1. Go to the product where you want to add an image.
2. Go the attribute.
3. Check this Mark

4. If this option did not show then you have to do the attributes.
5. First Creat a parent and select its type as an image and then on that attribute.
6. Make there Child and add images there
7. Then the issue Will be Solve and the Check is shown on there.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for. They are asking to add images to the description field.