# Add a WYSIWYG editor to the Variation Description in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wysiwyg, product-variations

Is it possible to put a WYSIWYG editor for the Variation Description?

[image]

Comment: No, it's not possible as it disables Ajax variations loading (making an infinite loading spinning animation)… I already have tried and some others too, nobody has been able it make it work (for instance).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add or replace a variation fields into a WYSIWYG editor field in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867300/add-or-replace-a-variation-fields-into-a-wysiwyg-editor-field-in-woocommerce)